# Count all elements with a certain class where it's data-attr contains number

Tags: jquery

Trying to get a count of each element that has the class "`active`" and it's input attr, "`data-price`", contains just a number/price between the `[&quot;&quot]`.

So, if tot element count is > 0, do something...

HTML

```
<ul class="elem-ul">
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;100&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;400&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery
I am not sure how to get the number from the input attr

```
$('.elem-ul .elem-label.active').each(function(){
  var elemCt = $('input.elem-input', this).attr('data-price').length;
  if(elemCt > 0){
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you need the data-price for? do you just want to print it?

Comment: @NickParsons I just wanted to see if any element are true to fire a function

Comment: @samjco can't you just do `if(elemCt > 4)` as you know it isn't empty if it is greater than four because `[""]` (an empty attribute) is 4 characters long and so if a number where in it it would be longer than 4 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the number within the quotes is greater than `0` by using the `.data()` method instead of the `.attr()` method. Using `.data()` will give you an array as a return value and so you can target index `0` to get the string number from that array. You can then use `.length` to get the length of this number.

See working example below:

```js
$('.elem-ul .elem-label.active').each(function(){
  var elem =  $('input.elem-input', this).data('price')[0]
  var elemCt = elem.length;
  if(elemCt > 0){
    //do something
    console.log("The elements price is: " +elem);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="elem-ul">
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;100&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;400&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
</ul>
```

Or you can instead check if `elemCt` is greater than four if you decide to stick with using `.attr()`. At the moment when there is no number between the quotes your getting a string which looks like `[""]`. So if you take the length of this string you will get `4`. So you know that if the string is more than 4 characters long then it has a number within the quotes.

```js
$('.elem-ul .elem-label.active').each(function(){
  var elem = $('input.elem-input', this).attr('data-price');
  var elemCt = elem.length;
  if(elemCt > 4){
    //do something
    console.log("The data-price is " +elem);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="elem-ul">
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;100&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;400&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label active">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
    <li class="elem-li">
        <label class="elem-label">    
            <input class="elem-input" data-price="[&quot;&quot;]" type="checkbox">
       </label>         
   </li>
</ul>
```